# Transformer different resulting current and voltage than expected

Tags: transformer, current-measurement, oscilloscope, measurement, current-transformer

I am uncertain why the current on the secondary side does not follow the equation:

$$i_2 = \frac{N_1}{N_2} i_1$$

which gives

$$i_2 = \frac{20}{3} i_1$$

To measure the current I use two 1 ohm resistors (one on the primary side, and one on the secondary side) that I measure the voltage drop across using an oscilloscope (Keysight InfiniiVision MSO-X 3012T).

By adjusting the signal generator (inside the oscilloscope) to output a sine wave with an amplitude of 2.5 V, that is, 5 V peak-to-peak, and a frequency anywhere between 10 kHz and 20 MHz, I get that the secondary current is lower than the primary current. From 2 MHz to 10 MHz the amplitude of the secondary current is about 1/3 that of the primary current.

Measuring over the resistance at channel 1 gives a sine with amplitude of 50 mV for most frequencies, that would mean that a sine current of 50 mA is flowing through the resistor and the primary coil. From the equation I would then expect a current of 333 mA at the secondary side, and thus a voltage drop of 333 mV across the resistor on the secondary side. But instead I get currents below 30 mA on the secondary side for all frequencies.

I have the following toroidal core from FERROXCUBE: [TN23/14/7-4C65](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0vBx.png) (link leads to product page at Farnell.com, datasheet is available here).

The image shows how the circuit is wired. Left side is the primary side, and the right side is the secondary side. The reference of the signal generator and all channels are connected directly to ground inside the oscilloscope, that is, the oscilloscope is of the type with common reference.
[image]

Comment: What load are you putting on the secondary to draw current? Note that the primary current includes magnetising current, how have you allowed for that?

Comment: Right now the only load on the secondary is that 1 ohm resistor. And I had forgotten about the magnetizing current, so I have not really thought about it. I am not sure if you have looked at the datasheet, but the information there is really limited. So I don't quite know how to find the values that I need to calculate this. Could try sending an email to FERROXCUBE.

Comment: Are those differential probes? Or are you connecting the probe ground at different parts of your circuit?

Comment: They are not differential no, the reference of the oscilloscope, the signal generator and the probes is ground. So yes, I am connecting different parts of the circuit to ground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the diagram below (a typical power transformer equivalent circuit), you'll see a red arrow that I have marked. That red arrow indicates that a current will flow into the primary winding even when the secondary is unloaded. That current will make the assumption about the secondary current and primary current relationship flawed: -

[image]

The magnetization inductance can be found from the [data sheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1487127.pdf) of your toroid: -

[image]

Multiply the turns squared by 87 nH to get the magnetization inductance.

If you have 20 turns then \$L_{MAG} = 34.8\text{ } \mu H\$. How much current will this take - you need to factor that into your calculations. However, at the low end of your stated spectrum (10 kHz), the impedance of 34.8 μH is 2.18 ohms and is really dominant. It becomes less dominant at higher frequencies of course.

> *From 2 MHz to 10 MHz the amplitude of the secondary current is about
> 1/3 that of the primary current*

That's a decent enough frequency to avoid the magnetization inductance problem so then it boils down to leakage inductance and copper loss. For instance, if the net series copper loss (referred to your secondary) is (say) a couple of Ω, then you will lose a significant ability to drive current into the 1 Ω load resistor. You could try using a load resistor that is bigger of course. Then there's leakage inductance (whose impedance rises with frequency) and, at some point this may become quite dominant.

For instance, if the leakage inductance is about 5% of the magnetization inductance it will have a value of around 1.7 μH. At 2 MHz, this has an impedance of 21.4 Ω. Do you see the problem here?

If we referred the load resistance back to the primary is would be seen as a resistance of: -

$$\left(\frac{20}{3}\right)^2 \cdot 1 \text{ }\Omega = 44 \text{ }\Omega$$

And clearly a leakage impedance of 21.4 Ω is going to have some effect at 2 MHz but, at 10 MHz it is going to dwarf the 44 Ω referred load impedance and radically reduce current in the secondary.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware that that was the magnetizing inductance. I will look into this.

Comment: @TheJonaMr maybe you should also [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand the motivation behind people giving free help. When you understand this, you'll realize there's no need to say "thank you" but, it's always welcome as well!

Comment: I saw your new edits just now, and they are great, will read into them soon. I am still working on this but I believe that I have good progress. I have tried to find the leakage inductance based on a method mentioned at the following link under "The traditional solution". I did this using a oscilloscope and the built-in signal generator, applied a square wave, and found the time constant of the discharge, instead of using LCR-meter. Then i found that the leakage inductance is 6.148 nH. Not sure if that is reasonable though.
https://www.voltech.com/Articles/104-105/1_What_is_Leakage_Inductance

Comment: @TheJonaMr that sounds a little too low for my liking. It would imply a coupling factor between the coils that would be possibly too good even for a toroid.

Comment: Nice induction, Andy.

Comment: Is that a play on the word "introduction" @MituRaj

Comment: You got it.. 

Comment: @Andyaka yes I see that now, I mistook the total leakage induction on the secondary to be the same as the one on the primary. I see now that due to reflected impedance through the transformer the total leakage inductance seen from either side will be different, and in this case larger in what is primary in my case.
I conducted new measurements and found the leakage inductance to be 3.825 uH.
Does this seem like a more reasonable value?

I initially took my measurements from the secondary side, since it was easier with my setup (not that it required a lot of work to do it from the primary).

Comment: @TheJonaMr yes, that is entirely what the fight is about with leakage inductance. About 3 to 5% is about right for a good toroid but, factoring the low permeability of the material (4C65) means you will have a battle on your hands to achieve this. I expect that you want primary and secondary to be not wound on top of each other.

Comment: Well right now they are not wound on top of each other, and I do not know how that would affect my circuit. Personally I can not think of a reason not to wind them on top of each other, other than the safety associated with keeping them apart, considering eventual shorts (Not that I find it that likely to happen).

Comment: If you can live with them wound over each other, you should get improved (lower) leakage inductance.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean when you say that I will lose a significant ability to drive current into the 1 Ω load resistor?

Comment: @TheJonaMr I mean that with a series resistance of a couple of ohms inherent in your windings (just a number I pulled from thin air), you won't be able to deliver as much current into the 1 ohm load as you thought you should.

Comment: @TheJonaMr if we are done here then maybe you should consider closing down this Q and A session - [read this to understand what you should consider doing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) - it's called "answer acceptance" but, if you still have unresolved issues relating to your original question, then leave another comment.

Comment: Hi, I am still working on this, I have a lot to do right now since I am writing my Bachelor thesis. I will most likely accept this answer as the answer of my question since it has helped me a lot. But I will wait with that until I am finished with this part of the project, which will be sometime next week.

Comment: @Andyaka where did you get the 3% - 5% leakage to magnetization inductance ratio from?

Comment: From my experiences using such things @TheJonaMr - If the mag inductance is 1 henry, then a typical leakage will be about 30 to 50 mH.